# Load DB through jQuery on intervals "plus" allow infinite scroll to append older data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I am facing a problem with the two options are merged into one.

On one hand, loading content through `jQuery.ajax()` is working fine.
On page loading the news, `updateNews()` is called which uses `jQuery.ajax()` to pull content from the database. It then sets up an interval, `setInterval()` to call the function every 50sec to update the pages with new data coming in from a site (i.e. twitter).

```
setInterval(function () {updateNews();},50000);
```

On the other hand, loading content from the database when a user scroll to the bottom  of the page is working fine. 
The code, based on a defined number of rows per query (limit), pulls the results needed to and based on `$(window).scroll()` position, gets the data

```
$.post('get_entries.php',{'group_no': group_no}, function(data){});
```

Now the problem comes when putting these two together. I want new content to continue coming in through the set interval while also allowing the user to scroll down and get older content/news.
When I tried to put those together without an idea on how to get them to jive together, I ended up with two problems (at least):

1. Loading new content, `updateNews()` function, when the user is at the bottom of the page reset the page position to the top of the page.
2. When the `updateNews()` content is loaded, the SCROLL event fires (since the page height and scroll change due to the new content coming into the page) causing the loading of extra content without user interaction.

Can someone give me some hints, help, links, example.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?... its normal on scroll not time interval and if the scroll does it, then it serves no purpose to do the timed method

Comment: This is a good question. The news stream gets updated like Tweetdeck and if the user doesn't scroll for old news and wants to stick to the new items at the top of the page. If I ignore the update on intervals and the user doesn't scroll there won't be new data coming in.

Comment: But if the user doesn't scroll then the user doesn't want to read anything else... what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe store news in some variable array and take a close look on $.merge and $.unique

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: I am looking for the same functionality that you see if you are familiar with TweetDeck. You can scroll down for old tweets but can also get the new ones pushed to the top of the stream.

Comment: @Zentoaku: I will take a look at those and see what I can do through them, thanks!